# Relative path to source when copying or moving

Tags: command-line, bash, paths

<sub>This might be trivial, but here goes.</sub>

In terminal, I tend to find myself moving/renaming/copying files that are not in my current working directory instead of `cd`-ing to the directory of those files first. For example, I find myself doing:

```
mv long/path/to/a/folder long/path/to/a/folder.old
```

Sometimes, this can be a `"long/path with spaces/to/a/folder"`.

My question is: is there a way/shortcut for the `<target path>` to be relative to the `<source path>`? For instance, does something like this exist:

```
mv long/path/to/a/folder ``/folder.old
```

Where ``` `` ``` means "the same path or the same parent path of the file/folder I'm trying to move", so in my example ``` `` ``` would stand for `long/path/to/a/`.

I know I could of course `cd long/path/to/a/` and then `mv folder folder.old`, but that involves an extra command, and I'll end up in another working directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
mv long/path/to/a/folder{,.old}
```

Reference: search for **Brace Expansion** in bash [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/bash.1.html).

Comment: Beautiful. Is there also an alternative solution with arguments?

Comment: @Private I don't get it. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I once saw something like `cp /long/path/ $1/` where $1 would be the first argument, but I am really not sure so I was wondering whether you knew of an alternative like that.

Comment: @Private I don't know if that's possible somehow. Surely it isn't possible using positional parameters ($0, $1, ...).